Is there a way to make window either spawning or changing from tiled to floating take the earlier size and place?
I know that I can tell bspwm to spawn windows in specified desktop or monitor in tiled mode or in certain shape and position via floating mode. But I am looking for the window to remember its previous floating mode state. Bspwm doc is not written in comprehensive way. I read it once, and I will read it again, looking for this in case I missed it last time. But I am almost sure that bspwm might provide a way to spawn windows in floating mode in its previous state, but it doesn't provide a way to change the window state from tiled to the same previous floating state when it was closed or changed from.
I believe if it can't be done through the already provided options, then it can be done with a script. Making a script won't be the difficult part. The difficulty part would be to make it general and robust. If I need to make a script, then I might need some help. I need your guidance and opinions(in case I am missing something).
